Payment redirecct issues using sslcommerz
There is an issue with my code. After payment, it redirects here http://localhost:5173/order/$%7Border._id%7D' order?.\_id is not undefined. But Page displays an error; something like the: site can't be reached.
But if I copy this URL, open another tab and paste it, then it works. Please help me.. Thanks in advance.
Here is my code
    export const createPayment = async (req, res) => {
      if (!req.body) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: "No request body", success: false });
      }
      if (req.user.isAdmin) {
        return res
          .status(503)
          .json({ message: "Admins cannot make payments", success: false });
      }
    
      // console.log("payment", data);
      try {
        const order = await Order.findById(req.params.id);
        console.log("order", order);
        if (!order) {
          return res
            .status(404)
            .json({ message: "Order not found", success: false });
        }
    
        const tran_id = uuidv4();
    
        const data = {
          total_amount: order.totalPrice,
          currency: "BDT",
          tran_id,
          success_url: `http://localhost:5173/order/${order._id}`, // Redirect here on success
          fail_url: `http://localhost:5173/order/${order._id}`, // Redirect here on failure
          cancel_url: `http://localhost:5173/order/${order._id}`,
          ipn_url: "http://localhost:3030/ipn",
          shipping_method: "Courier",
    
          product_name: "something",
          product_category: "something",
          product_profile: order.orderItems
            .map((item) => item.imagesUrls[0])
            .join(", "),
          cus_name: order.deliveryAddress.name,
          cus_email: order.deliveryAddress.email,
          cus_address: order.deliveryAddress.address,
          cus_country: "Bangladesh",
          cus_phone: order.deliveryAddress.phone,
          // Add the missing field
          ship_name: order.deliveryAddress.name, // Shipping name
          ship_add1: order.deliveryAddress.address,
          ship_city: "Dhaka",
          ship_state: "Dhaka",
          ship_postcode: 1000,
          ship_country: "Bangladesh",
        };
    
        const sslcz = new SSLCommerzPayment(store_id, store_password, isLive);
        const apiResponse = await sslcz.init(data);
    
        // console.log(apiResponse.status);
        // Redirect the user to the payment gateway
        let GatewayPageURL = apiResponse.GatewayPageURL;
        // console.log(GatewayPageURL);
        res.send(GatewayPageURL);
        if (apiResponse.status === "SUCCESS") {
          order.isPaid = true;
          order.isAvailable = false;
          order.paidAt = Date.now();
          order.transactionId = tran_id;
          // order.user = req.user.id;
          const bookIds = order.orderItems.map((item) => item.product);
          const orderType = order.orderItems.map((item) => item.orderType);
    
          await Promise.all(
            order.orderItems.map(async (item) => {
              await Book.updateOne(
                { _id: item.product },
                { $set: { bookStatus: item.orderType, isAvailable: false } }
              );
            })
          );
    
          // order.paidAt = Date.now();
          await order.save();
          // console.log("new Order", order);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message, success: false });
      }
    };

What I want is that after successful payment, it should redirect to my target page or URL.
Below is my what handler function looks like on the frontend:
     const handlePay = async () => {
        Swal.fire({
          title: "Are you sure ?",
          icon: "success",
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: "#3085d6",
          cancelButtonColor: "#d33",
          confirmButtonText: "Yes, continue it!",
        }).then(async (result) => {
          if (result.isConfirmed) {
            // console.log(order, orderId);
            const res = await paymentServer(order, orderId);
    
            if (res?.data) {
              console.log("Opening URL: ", res.data);
             
              window.open(res.data, "_blank");
            } else {
              console.error("Invalid URL");
              console.log(res);
            }
    
            // console.log(res);
            setPolling(true);
          }
        });
      }; 
   const paymentServer = async (data, id) => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
          // console.log("f", data, id);
          const res = await axiosPublic.put(
            `/api/order/createPayment/${id}`,
            data,
            {
              withCredentials: true,
            }
          );
          return res;
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          return error;
        } finally {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      };



Please include the frontend code that integrates the createPayment handler function.

You should update it in your question and not in the comment

Yeah ,Mr.Hamed Jimoh ,i update it

When you enter a URL in the browser's address bar, it sends a GET request. Since copying the URL in the browser tab works, it indicates that your route is set up as a GET route.
However, SSLCommerz uses a POST method for redirection, so you need to provide a URL that accepts POST requests as your callback URL.
Ideally, you should set your backend URL as the callback URL, handle the business logic in the corresponding method, and then redirect to your frontend from there.
